# How do I output a mix of str, UTF-8, & int to a text file?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a tuple containing string data (UTF-8), binary (true/false/1/0) & integer data that I want to output as a row in my output file.  A portion of my code is:

```
###  Python 2.73

import fileinput
import re
import time
import codecs

uIDfile = '\Python\Fav Test\ppl.ttxt'

InFile = open(uIDfile)
OutFile = codecs.open('C:\Python\Fav Test\S2.ttxt', encoding='utf-8', mode='w')

for user in InFile:
    user = user [:-1]
#   user = unicode(user, 'utf-8').encode('utf-8')

    if 'NNNN' in user:
        break
    else:
        if '@N' in user:
            try:
                Grp = people_getGroups(user_id = user)
                g = 0
                if GetAll:
                    for group in Grp.find('groups').findall('group'):

                        g += 1
                        fErr = ''
                        uID  = user
                        gID  = group.get('ID')
                        gName  =  group.get('name')
                        tup = '\"{0}\"\t\"{2}\"\t\"{1}\"\t''\t{3}\t{4}\t{5}\t{6}\n'.format(uNSID, gNSID, gName, bin1, bin2, int1, int2)
                        OutFile.write(tup.encode('utf-8'))
```

I've tried several different versions of the "OutFile.write()" statement.  The errors are listed below each.

```
OutFile.write(codecs.utf_8_decode(tup.encode('utf-8')))
    TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, tuple found

OutFile.write('\t'.join(codecs.utf_8_decode(tup.encode('utf-8'))))
    TypeError: sequence item 1: expected string or Unicode, int found

OutFile.write('\t'.join(map(str, codecs.utf_8_decode(tup.encode('utf-8')))))
    tup = '\"{0}\"\t\"{2}\"\t\"{1}\"\t""\t\"{3}\"\t\"{4}\"\t\"{5}\"\t\"{6}\"\n'.format(uNSID, gNSID, gName, str(bin1), str(bin2), str(int1), str(int2))
    UnicodeEncodeError: "'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: ordinal not in range(128)"

OutFile.write('\t'.join(map(str, codecs.utf_8_decode(tup.encode('utf-8')))))
    tup = '\"{0}\"\t\"{2}\"\t\"{1}\"\t""\t\"{3}\"\t\"{4}\"\t\"{5}\"\t\"{6}\"\n'.format(uNSID, gNSID, gName, bin1, bin2, int1, int2)
    UnicodeEncodeError: "'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: ordinal not in range(128)"
```

Any help is sincerely appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to output rows in a file, I suggest you to use the [csv module](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7.3/library/csv.html). Here is an example of how it can be used :

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import csv
# Use of tempfile instead of hard-coded path, to be cross-platform :)
import tempfile
_, tmppath = tempfile.mkstemp()
out = open(tmppath, 'w')
writer = csv.writer(out)
input = "Te×t Ðåtå".decode('utf-8')
tup = (input.encode('utf-8'), 42, False)
tup
# OUT: ('Te\xc3\x97t \xc3\x90\xc3\xa5t\xc3\xa5', 42, False)
writer.writerow(tup)
out.close()
print(u"Look at me : {}".format(tmppath))
```

You can use the [Dialects and Formatting Parameters](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7.3/library/csv.html#csv-fmt-params) to precisely define how the ouput file must be formatted.

To avoid UTF8 jamming, the good practice, as explained in these [good slides](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/) are :

- Decode early
- Unicode everywhere
- Encode late

Comment: That works great where "Te×t Ðåtå" goes directly into tup, but how does it work when it comes from a variable, such as `uTxt = "Te×t Ðåtå"`  `tup = (uTxt.encode('utf-8'), 42, False)`?  
In reality, that's not even right, since uTxt will actually be reading a field in a file as in `uTxt = group.get('name').encode('utf-8')`

Comment: When reading from file, or anywhere, you have to apply the "Decode early" principle. I'll edit my answer to that point (but using only a variable, for code readability and easy execution).

Comment: Thank you for your help!  I found the problem: I was using `OutFile = codecs.open('C:\Python\Fav Test\S2.ttxt', encoding='utf-8', mode='w')` so it still gave me an error.  When I changed it to `OutFile = open('C:\Python\Fav Test\S2.ttxt', 'w')` it runs fine!